# Hide CMS static block programmatically in Magento 2

Tags: blocks, cms

I need to Hide static cms block "block-id-1" from frontpage programmatically customer group based. I need to add event to hide cms static block or any other method. I want to use admin interface to enable/disable customer group to hide "block-id-1".

Content of block-cms-id-1 is button which is currently display for all customer group on checkout/cart

Mainly I need to connect this block id to customer group which can be enable from admin>configuration>extension_name>Hide from groups

Comment: what is means by `cms static block or any other method. ` other method?

Comment: Backend admin>content>block> "block-cms-id-1" , Here block ID can be any name. I need to hide static block programmatically.

Comment: Here other method means if not possible to hide block ID, then I can call block ID to phtml file vendor/module/view/frontend/customfile.phtml Then even to hide html data group based. Need code to run vendor/module/observer/customfile to run event e.g. public function execute(Observer $observer) { if command ...} I've tried $layout = $observer->getLayout();
        $block = $layout->getBlock('static-block-id-1'); This will not run as I think this code is for dynamic magento core ID. I've tried javascript to hide but unable to connect to group so that this can enable/disable from backend.

Answer (score 1):

Magento renders a cms block using `\Magento\Cms\Block\Block` at frontend.

So, if you want to stop rendering a cms block based on customer group then create
an after plugin on  `Magento\Cms\Block\Block:toHtml()` and stop rendering the content for some customer groups.

**Create di.xml at your module:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Cms\Block\Block">
        <plugin disabled="false" name="Devamitbera_StackExchange_Plugin_Magento_Cms_Block_Block" sortOrder="10" type="Devamitbera\StackExchange\Plugin\Magento\Cms\Block\Block"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

##Plugin class

```
<?php

namespace Devamitbera\StackExchange\Plugin\Magento\Cms\Block;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Context as CustomerContext;

class Block
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context
     */
    protected $httpContext;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext
    ){
        $this->httpContext = $httpContext;
    }
    public function afterToHtml(\Magento\Cms\Block\Block $subject, $result) {
        $blockId = $subject->getBlockId();
        $customerGroupId = $this->httpContext->getValue(CustomerContext::CONTEXT_GROUP);
        /**
         * If customer group id X match then
         */
        if($customerGroupId === '2'){
            return '';
        }
        return $result;
    }

    /***
     * Add Customer Group to cache
     * @param \Magento\Cms\Block\Block $subject
     * @param $result
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function afterGetCacheKeyInfo(\Magento\Cms\Block\Block $subject, $result)
    {
       if(!empty($result)){
           $result[] =  $this->httpContext->getValue(CustomerContext::CONTEXT_GROUP);
       }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've re-edited question in details. Please tell me in more details to implement, guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any magento developer here to solve this complex implementation.